# JQuery conditions based on "screen width"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am super new to Javascript/JQuery, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I want to add it to a responsive site that I am working on in class.

I have a hamburger menu set up that hides/shows my menu, which works great.  The thing is I only want the Javascript to run on a screen width of 414px or less. My menu is to be hidden until I click the hamburger.

For screens 415px, and above I don't want it to hide my menu, or show the hamburger and "X". I can hide the "X" and the hamburger easily enough with media queries if needed, but I still need my menu to display.

I tried to add an event loader, but must have done something wrong, as everything turned on (X, hamburger, & menu), and clicking did nothing.  Please help me figure out how to make this work.  I am super green at this, so any pointer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time

```
    // Hamburger menu
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".hamburger").click(function () {
            $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $(".hamburger").hide();
                $(".cross").show();
            });
        });

        $(".cross").click(function () {
            $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $(".cross").hide();
                $(".hamburger").show();
            });
        });
      });
```

Comment: I think you're missunderstanding what JavaScript is. You want to disable it, why?

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help debug your script if you can provide the accompanying HTML markup (ideally in a snippet that shows what goes wrong in your current implementation.)

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren, I think Mtullis doesn't mean to "disable" JS in the browser, just to run the script conditionally.

Comment: window.innerWidth gives you width in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery ***width()*** to get the current page width, and use it as a condition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   WindowWidth = $(window).width();
   if (WindowWidth < 415){
      do logic...
   }
   else {
      do other logic...
   }
}
```

But remember that people often resize their screens so you need to handle that as well.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   WindowWidth = $(window).width();
   if (WindowWidth < 415){
      do logic...
   }
   else {
      do other logic...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @m4dm0nk3y

I usually extract the common code in a function and call it on `ready`, and then on `resize`.

```js
function alignStuff() {

  WindowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (WindowWidth < 415) {
    console.log('small');
  } else {
    console.log('large');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alignStuff();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
  alignStuff();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```